# streaming webcam output over the internet using UDP protocol

Tags: udp, streaming, video-streaming, directshow, rtp

I want to stream webcam output over the internet using UDP protocol (RTP to be specific). But I don’t have any ideas how to start to do so.
I have already tried using Microsoft DirectShow to get every frame as a jpeg file. I tried to send it using UDP but it was very slow.
I hope you could point me to the right direction .Also, if there are open source applications in java or c# that does this I will be very happy to work on them.
Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you can use ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that VLC (http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) can do RTP.

- Media menu
- Stream...
- Capture device tab
- Set up as appropriate
- Stream button
- Next button
- Change the "new destination" drop down to one of the RTP options
- after this, I don't know, because I've never used RTP.

Good luck!